# pythonでファイルに入っている複数枚の画像をn×mで連結して、１枚の画像として出力したいです

Tags: python3, 画像, array

以下のコードでファイルに入っている画像を順に並べて１枚の画像にしたいです。
（5×9）枚で画像枚数は42~50で枠が足りなくてもあふれても最初の１枚目からから最高４５枚だけ出力させたいです。
問題としてはIndexError: list index out of rangeが出てしまいます。
よろしくお願いします。
[image: コード]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

動作確認はしていませんが、ご質問のフォーマットに合わせるとこんな感じですかね。
イメージファイルの数を取得しておいて、それ以上になったらbreakでループを抜けます。
最低1個のイメージファイルが必要です。

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import cv2, os, glob

fn = glob.glob('\\Users\y\Desktop\resize\*.jpg')
l = len(fn)
k = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(9):
        if k >= l:break
        im = np.array(Image.open(fn[k]))
        if j == 0:im1 = im
        else:im1 = np.hstack((im1,im))
        k += 1
    if i == 0:im2 = im1
    else:im2 = np.vstack((im2,im1))
    if k >= l:break
cv2.imwrite('\\Users\y\Desktop\stack.jpg', im2)
```

---

@metropolisさんの指摘を受けて、あらかじめダミーのブランクイメージをファイルなり
何かの処理で初期化したデータなりで準備して、残り位置に穴埋めすれば良いのでは？
以下はファイルで用意した例となるでしょう。

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import cv2, os, glob

blank = np.array(Image.open('blank.jpg'))
fn = glob.glob('\\Users\y\Desktop\resize\*.jpg')
l = len(fn)
k = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(9):
        if k < l:im = np.array(Image.open(fn[k]))
        else:im = blank.copy()
        if j == 0:im1 = im
        else:im1 = np.hstack((im1,im))
        k += 1
    if i == 0:im2 = im1
    else:im2 = np.vstack((im2,im1))
    if k >= l:break
cv2.imwrite('\\Users\y\Desktop\stack.jpg', im2)
```

Comment: 画像ファイル数が 9 の倍数ではない場合(例えば 44 枚)、shape が合わないので `np.vstack()` でエラーになってしまいます(`all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`) 。